# Fetch descriptive custom message of exception thrown from server at RestTemplate Client

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, resttemplate

I am using Spring 3.0.5 Rest Full WebService.

At client side using `RestTemplate` so my problem when server throw any exception with non-`HttpStatus.OK` response status.

Then **I want the exception message of server side  in client side through spring RestTemplate.** Presently what I am getting all time same exception (`ResourceAccessException`) with some generic message, for example got below exception on method failure status:

```
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error: Server returned HTTP response code: 420 for URL: https://<URL>:<Port>/<Server Application Name>/?param=12345; nested exception is java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 420 for URL: <URL>:<Port>/<Server Application Name>/?param=12345
```

**So at that time I want full descriptive custom message of exception thrown from server at `RestTemplate` Client**

Please help me out of this problem.

Comment: It seems spring 3.0.5 Issue [SPR-8713](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-8713?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel) which is fixed in Spring 3.0.7, have done some work around as can not upgrade spring version at release time :).

Answer (score 0):

I have answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15404605/spring-resttemplate-invoking-webservice-with-errors-and-analyze-status-code). You need to implement ResponseErrorHandler in order to intercept response code, body, and header when you get non-2xx response codes from the service when using rest template. Copy all the information you need, attach it to your custom exception and throw it back for the client to consume. You can see the code in the link above.