# Rest Template custom exception handling

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am using some REST endpoints from an external API and I am using the Rest Template interface for this purpose. I would like to be able to throw custom app exceptions when I receive certain HTTP status codes from these calls. In order to achieve it, I am implementing the ResponseErrorHandler interface as follows:

```
public class MyCustomResponseErrorHandler implements ResponseErrorHandler {

    private ResponseErrorHandler myErrorHandler = new DefaultResponseErrorHandler();

    public boolean hasError(ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException {
        return myErrorHandler.hasError(response);
    }

    public void handleError(ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException {
        String body = IOUtils.toString(response.getBody());
        MyCustomException exception = new MyCustomException(response.getStatusCode(), body, body);
        throw exception;
    }

}

public class MyCustomException extends IOException {

    private HttpStatus statusCode;

    private String body;

    public MyCustomException(String msg) {
        super(msg);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public MyCustomException(HttpStatus statusCode, String body, String msg) {
        super(msg);
        this.statusCode = statusCode;
        this.body = body;
    }

    public HttpStatus getStatusCode() {
        return statusCode;
    }

    public void setStatusCode(HttpStatus statusCode) {
        this.statusCode = statusCode;
    }

    public String getBody() {
        return body;
    }

    public void setBody(String body) {
        this.body = body;
    }

}
```

Finally, this is the client code (irrelevant code omitted):

```
public LoginResponse doLogin(String email, String password) {
    HttpEntity<?> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<Object>(crateBasicAuthHeaders(email,password));
    try{
        ResponseEntity<LoginResponse> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(myBaseURL + "/user/account/" + email, HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity, LoginResponse.class);
        return responseEntity.getBody();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //Custom error handler in action, here we're supposed to receive a MyCustomException
        if (e instanceof MyCustomException){
            MyCustomException exception = (MyCustomException) e;
            logger.info("An error occurred while calling api/user/account API endpoint: " + e.getMessage());
        } else {
             logger.info("An error occurred while trying to parse Login Response JSON object");
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

My app context:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:spring="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd">

    <!-- Rest template (used in bridge communication) -->
    <bean id="restTemplate" class="org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate">
        <property name="errorHandler" ref="myCustomResponseErrorHandler"></property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Bridge service -->
    <bean id="myBridgeService" class="a.b.c.d.service.impl.MyBridgeServiceImpl"/>

    <!-- Bridge error handler -->
    <bean id="myCustomResponseErrorHandler" class="a.b.c.d.service.handlers.MyCustomResponseErrorHandler"/>

</beans>
```

I suspect I am not correctly understanding the behaviour of this custom error handling. Every single rest template method might throw a RestClientException, which following the exception hierarchy, is a subclass of RuntimeException and not IOException, which is thrown in the custom response error handler, i.e.: I can't catch my custom exception in the rest template method calls.

Any clues on how I could catch these exceptions? [Spring RestTemplate invoking webservice with errors and analyze status code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15404605/spring-resttemplate-invoking-webservice-with-errors-and-analyze-status-code) is highly related but from my point of view experiences the same problem, although it was proposed as a solution.

[1]:

Comment: You can visit bellow thread. It has full working code with description:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51805956/3073945

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You've made your custom `Exception` extend from `IOException`

```
public class MyCustomException extends IOException {
```

The `ResponseErrorHandler#handleError()` method is invoked from `RestTemplate#handleResponseError(..)` which is invoked by `RestTemplate#doExecute(..)`. This root invocation is wrapped in a `try-catch` block which catches `IOException` and rethrows it wrapped in a `ResourceAccessException`, which is a `RestClientException`.

One possibility is to catch the `RestClientException` and get its `cause`.

Another possibility is to make your custom `Exception` be a sub type of `RuntimeException`.

Comment: What is the best approach here? What if my Exception must inherit from Exception, I would have to get the Exception behin RestClientException everytime when using RestTemplate

Comment: @Zarathustra I don't think you can have another type of checked exception. `handleError` is only declared to throw `IOException`. Unless you're talking about some other component, those are the only two options, `IOException` or a unchecked exception.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a controller using annotation `@ControllerAdvice` if you using springmvc. In the controller write:

```
@ExceptionHandler(HttpClientErrorException.class)
public String handleXXException(HttpClientErrorException e) {
    log.error("log HttpClientErrorException: ", e);
    return "HttpClientErrorException_message";
}

@ExceptionHandler(HttpServerErrorException.class)
public String handleXXException(HttpServerErrorException e) {
    log.error("log HttpServerErrorException: ", e);
    return "HttpServerErrorException_message";
}
...
// catch unknown error
@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
public String handleException(Exception e) {
    log.error("log unknown error", e);
    return "unknown_error_message";
}
```

and the `DefaultResponseErrorHandler` throw these two kinds of  exceptions:

```
@Override
public void handleError(ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException {
    HttpStatus statusCode = getHttpStatusCode(response);
    switch (statusCode.series()) {
        case CLIENT_ERROR:
            throw new HttpClientErrorException(statusCode, response.getStatusText(),
                    response.getHeaders(), getResponseBody(response), getCharset(response));
        case SERVER_ERROR:
            throw new HttpServerErrorException(statusCode, response.getStatusText(),
                    response.getHeaders(), getResponseBody(response), getCharset(response));
        default:
            throw new RestClientException("Unknown status code [" + statusCode + "]");
    }
}
```

and you can get using:`e.getResponseBodyAsString();`，`e.getStatusCode();` blabla to get response message when the exceptions occurs.