# Spring RestTemplate - Overriding ResponseErrorHandler

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, resttemplate

I am calling a `ReST` service through `RestTemplate` and trying to override `ResponseErrorHandler` in `Spring 3.2` to handle custom error codes.

**CustomResponseErrroHandler**

```
public class MyResponseErrorHandler implements ResponseErrorHandler {

    @Override
    public boolean hasError(ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException {
        boolean hasError = false;
        int rawStatusCode = response.getRawStatusCode();
        if (rawStatusCode != 200){
            hasError = true;
        }
        return hasError;
     }

    @Override
    public void handleError(ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException {
        //String body = IOUtils.toString(response.getBody());
        throw new CustomServiceException(response.getRawStatusCode() , "custom Error");
   }
}
```

`Spring` framework invokes `hasError` method but not `handleError`, so I couldn't throw my custom exception. After delving into `Spring` `RestTemplate` source code, I realized that the code in `handleResponseError` method is causing the issue - It is looking for `response.getStatusCode` or `response.getStatusText` and throwing exception (as statusCode/statusText is null when `Rest` service throws exception) and it never calls either custom implemented or default `handleError` method in the next line.

`Spring` `RestTemplate` source code for `handleResponse` method:

```
private void handleResponseError(HttpMethod method, URI url, ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException {
    if (logger.isWarnEnabled()) {
        try {
            logger.warn(method.name() + " request for \"" + url + "\" resulted in " +
response.getStatusCode() + " (" + response.getStatusText() + "); invoking error handler");
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            // ignore
        }
    }
    getErrorHandler().handleError(response);
}
```

FYI, while service throws exception, I can read rawstatuscode but not statuscode from response

How to bypass this framework code and make call  my custom handler?
Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: You can check bellow thread.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51805956/3073945

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38093388/spring-resttemplate-exception-handling

Answer (score 17):

Following link has useful information about [Exception Flow for Spring ResponseErrorHandler](https://web.archive.org/web/20161219213020/http://www.thetekblog.com/2010/12/spring-resttemplate-errormessagehandler/) .

Adding code here, just in-case the blog is down:

Code for ErrorHandler:

```
public class MyResponseErrorHandler implements ResponseErrorHandler {

    private static final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(MyResponseErrorHandler.class);

    @Override
    public void handleError(ClientHttpResponse clienthttpresponse) throws IOException {

        if (clienthttpresponse.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN) {
            logger.debug(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN + " response. Throwing authentication exception");
            throw new AuthenticationException();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasError(ClientHttpResponse clienthttpresponse) throws IOException {

        if (clienthttpresponse.getStatusCode() != HttpStatus.OK) {
            logger.debug("Status code: " + clienthttpresponse.getStatusCode());
            logger.debug("Response" + clienthttpresponse.getStatusText());
            logger.debug(clienthttpresponse.getBody());

            if (clienthttpresponse.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN) {
                logger.debug("Call returned a error 403 forbidden resposne ");
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Code for using it in RestTemplate:

```
RestTemplate restclient = new RestTemplate();
restclient.setErrorHandler(new MyResponseErrorHandler());
ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = clientRestTemplate.exchange(
                    URI,
                    HttpMethod.GET,
                    requestEntity,
                    String.class);
                response = responseEntity.getBody();
```

Comment: This seems like a pretty bad implementation of the hasError() method because it only returns true if the service returns a forbidden error. A much better implementation is one implemented here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/15685964/10792

Answer (score 4):

I don't see your `RestTemplate` code, but I assume you to set your `ResponseErrorHandler` for `RestTemplate` to use like:

```
RestTemplate restClient = new RestTemplate();
restClient.setErrorHandler(new MyResponseErrorHandler());
```

The exception is indeed thrown in `handleError` method. You can find how to throw `CustomException` using `CustomResponseHandler` from [one of my previous answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15404605/spring-resttemplate-invoking-webservice-with-errors-and-analyze-status-code).

Comment: Nilesh, I tried and it didn't work. To hit custom handleError it should first reach hanldeResponseError() method in RestTempalte and it decides which handleError() it should call but hanldeResponseError() is throwing exception as statuscode is null and it never reach next line. I provided RestTemplate handleResponseError() method code in previous post. FYI, I was trying through spring configuration, now I tried setting manually in code.  Either way it didn't work

Comment: FYI, It is not reaching either custom or default HandleError() to throw CustomException as exception is thrown in caller method handleResponseError() as statuscode is null.