# SpringFramework 400 response return empty data

Tags: java, android, spring

I am currently using springframework for consuming webservices in android. All was working fine but now I have been stuck. I need to consume response even when there is some bad condition i.e. even if there is status code 400 , 404, etc. Is there someone who could get me out of this trouble as I don't want to switch for any other library.

```
result=RestTemplateUtil.getRestTemplateForHeaders() .postForObject(url,reques‌​t,responseType,map);
```

Comment: can you please add some code sample and you have done so far!

Comment: result=RestTemplateUtil.getRestTemplateForHeaders()    .postForObject(url,request,responseType,map);

it is working fine when response status is 200 but when it is 400 or somethinbg else it is returning response status but object is null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement a custom `org.springframework.web.client.ResponseErrorHandler` and configure your RestTemplateUtil to use it as an error handler.

More details in this article here [spring-resttemplate-overriding-responseerrorhandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23838752/spring-resttemplate-overriding-responseerrorhandler)

Comment: You are a real champ Flip. You saved my day. It was my first question on stackoverflow and now I am a fan of it just because of you.

Comment: Same thing happened to me a while back :) an you'll see that soon enough you'll also be helping out others as well!